# How can i get animator specific state length ? And how to make a loop to be infinity?

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine

It's not getting animation clip length but animator state length.
I'm waiting 5 seconds but i want to wait until each state to finish playing.

```
yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
```

Instead 5 i want to get anim[index] length. But anim[index] doesn't have any length property.

The second goal is to make the while loop infinity so it will keep playing all the states all over again non stop.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor.Animations;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController controller;
    private AnimatorState[] states;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        states = GetStateNames(animator);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(QueueAnim(states));
        }
    }

    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
    {
        controller = animator ? animator.runtimeAnimatorController as UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController : null;
        return controller == null ? null : controller.layers.SelectMany(l => l.stateMachine.states).Select(s => s.state).ToArray();
    }

    IEnumerator QueueAnim(params AnimatorState[] anim)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < anim.Length)
        {
            if (index == anim.Length)
                index = 0;

            animator.Play(anim[index].name);

            yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
            index++;
        }
    }

    private void RollSound()
    {

    }

    private void CantRotate()
    {

    }

    private void EndRoll()
    {

    }

    private void EndPickup()
    {

    }
}
```

Update: 
This is what i tried now:

But when i press on A once it's playing one state only and if i click many times on A then it will play another state but that's it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor.Animations;
using UnityEngine;

public class SwitchAnimations : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Animator animator;
    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController controller;
    private AnimatorState[] states;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        animator = GetComponent<Animator>();
        states = GetStateNames(animator);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.A))
        {
            StartCoroutine(QueueAnim(states));
        }
    }

    private static UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorState[] GetStateNames(Animator animator)
    {
        controller = animator ? animator.runtimeAnimatorController as UnityEditor.Animations.AnimatorController : null;
        return controller == null ? null : controller.layers.SelectMany(l => l.stateMachine.states).Select(s => s.state).ToArray();
    }

    IEnumerator QueueAnim(AnimatorState[] anim)
    {
        int index = 0;

        while (index < anim.Length)
        {
            if (index == anim.Length)
                index = 0;

            animator.Play(anim[index].name);

            string name = anim[index].name;

            while (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(name) && animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
            {
                //Wait every frame until animation has finished
                yield return null;
            }
            index++;
        }
    }

    private void RollSound()
    {

    }

    private void CantRotate()
    {

    }

    private void EndRoll()
    {

    }

    private void EndPickup()
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: Unity has newer and better way of animation handling called 'Mechanim'. Its much easier to use (especially when you need to mix two or more animations). It contains default 'Idle' state , so you just need to assign your animation to 'Idle' and mark your animation as 'Loop' in inspector window. I suggest you to take a look on the official video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xx21y9eJq1U

Answer (score 2):

> I'm waiting 5 seconds but i want to wait until each state to finish
>   playing.

You don't need to get the state length in order to do this. You can use `GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo` and the `normalizedTime` to check when the animator has finished playing. Simply replace the `yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);` with the code below:

```
string name = anim[index].name;

while (animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName(name) && animator.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).normalizedTime < 1.0f)
{
    //Wait every frame until animation has finished
    yield return null;
}
```

If you want it loop forever just put it in another `while` loop.

Unrelated but I advice you to avoid using `params` in functions when using Unity. It's simply not worth it. Just use array instead. The reason has a lot to do with performance and this depends on how frequently the function is called.

Comment: Can you please check the update in my question ? I edited it with what i tried now according to your answer. It's playing only one state when i click on A and if i click many times on A it will play another state but that's it, it's not playing all the states in a row. And how should i make it playing the states non stop ? To put it in another third while loop ?

Comment: Put `Debug.Log(anim[index].name)` in the first `while` loop to make sure that it is playing all the animations then press "A" **once**. It should play animation and play the next one after the next one until it's done. Let me know if that's happening. Also check the log and see what it says

Comment: I added the Debug.Log and when i click on A only once it's showing the Log window after millisecond all the animations like this: Roll
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object)
<QueueAnim>c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/Animations/SwitchAnimations.cs:47)
UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine:InvokeMoveNext(IEnumerator, IntPtr) Then PickupObject
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) then Reload_Rifle
UnityEngine.Debug:Log(Object) it's not playing them jusy showing them at once in the debug.log winodw and show (object)

Answer (score 0):

try this one, there you can save the length as a variable and keep using it

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/692593/get-animation-clip-length-using-animator.html